# Background image not showing when app is run on emulator

Tags: android, xml, logcat

A background image i made is not showing when its run on an emulator, instead a white screen shows up. Ive already looked through other posts and come up with nothing, the image is a 1080x1920 330ppi .png image.

---

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/synthesis_background"
    tools:context=".Login$PlaceholderFragment">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/txtback"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/txtback"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Synthesis"
        android:id="@+id/Brand"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
01-02 00:46:53.597    3163-3181/com.example.adrian.musicality D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-02 00:46:53.601    3163-3163/com.example.adrian.musicality D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xacf23980, tid 3163
01-02 00:48:08.551    3228-3246/com.example.adrian.musicality D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-02 00:48:08.554    3228-3228/com.example.adrian.musicality D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xacf23980, tid 3228
```

Answer (score 0):

The emulator simply does not have enough memory to render an image that large.

It'll show up on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

its probably because of the emulator settings, try to change the emulator settings to fit the resolution and the size of the image and make sure that the image is in res->drawable-hdpi folder